# How to create a circular linked list in Perl without using arrays?

Tags: algorithm, perl, data-structures

I've been assigned a task to create a circular linked list in Perl with given arguments, without using arrays or hashes to store the data, only using references. The first element in the structure has a value of 0, irrelevant to the input of the user. It should also support the traversal of the current chosen element using '-' and '+'. The output of the program always starts from the pre-defined element, with the value of 0. So the result should be like this:

```sh
./task.pl 3 2 1
0 3 2 1
./task.pl A D - B C + E
0 A B C D E
./task.pl A - B
0 B A
```

The current code I came up with is :

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @elements = @ARGV;

my ($first, $last);
$first = { value => '0', 'prev' => $first, 'next' => $first };

my $pointer = \$first;

for (@elements) {
    if ($_ == '-') {

    } elsif ($_ == '+') {

    } else {
        $_ = $pointer->{'next'};
        $_ = { value => "$_", 'prev' => $pointer, 'next' => undef};
        $pointer = \$_;
        $last = $_;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed further with this, also no imports like `Class::Struct` can be used.

Comment: There is an implementation in https://metacpan.org/pod/DataStructure::LinkedList. The nice thing about CPAN is that it's all just Perl, so you can go and read other people's code. This particular module seems to be object oriented and uses multiple classes, so is more advanced than what you are attempting to do. But it might be worth studying its code, and looking at its test cases. You might also want to look at Data::Printer, Data::Dumper and at Test::More.

Comment: Not quite sure I agree with your interpretation of how `+` and `-` works in the `A D - B C + E` example. If you insert A, then D AFTER A, then insert B BEFORE D, then C BEFORE D, then E AFTER D, that only makes sense if the `-` also changes the pointer to lock to D. Otherwise it should after B place C BEFORE B, since the pointer changes to B. Unless you consider `B C` a block and not 2 elements. Or reset direction and place C AFTER B. Likewise `+` should change direction after C and place E AFTER C. So the most logical result would be ACEBD, imo.

Comment: Also, your solution does include a hash, just in reference form. If you want to avoid hashes and arrays, you're going to need to figure out a way to hold 3 values in a single scalar, e.g. `SCALAR(0x2323)\0string1\0SCALAR(0x823fb)`, with reference to previous and next scalar value inside it, here separated by null bits.

Comment: I just noticed you said it's a circularly linked-list. It's unclear which node you consider the first node when it comes time to output.

Comment: I forgot to write that in the requirements of the task. The first element has a value of 0, and the output is always relative to it. Edited my question.

Comment: I have completed the task, it needed some tinkering, but your comment helped me to understand the structure itself really well. @ikegami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using a hash. `{}` creates a hash and returns a reference to it. THIS IS CORRECT. The hash is being used as a struct/class, which isn't what the assignment wants you to avoid.

Secondly, you have `$first` and `$last` and a bogus initial element. All of that is wrong. You just need my `my $pointer;`, although I would call it `my $current;`.

Thirdly, you use references to scalars (`\$var`). This is not useful here. The references to the hashes returned by `{}` are sufficient.

---

On to the code. There are three different components: Inserting the first element, `+` and `-`, insertions, and printing the list that was built.

**Inserting the first element**

The first argument is special. It can't be `+` and `-`. Other insertions always insert after another element, but that's not the case for the first insertion.

In short, we create a list that consists entirely of a node whose value is the first element.

We used `undef` to indicate a non-existent node.

```perl
my $pointer = { value => shift(@elements), prev => undef, next => undef };
```

**`+` and `-`**

`+` and `-` change the current node (as indicated by `$pointer`).

If `+` is received, you want `$pointer` to the point to the node to which the current node's `prev` field points.

If `-` is received, you want `$pointer` to the point to the node to which the current node's `prev` field points.

You always have to ask yourself if there's a special cases, and there is one for each of `+` and `-`. There could be an attempt to reach a node before the first (`A - -`), and there could be an attempt to reach a node after the last (`A +`). You should `die` if an attempt is made to reach a non-existent node.

**Insertions**

We always insert after the current node (the one `$pointer` references).

Again we ask ourselvves if there's a special case (like trying to use `-` when already at the first node). But there are none. `$pointer` will always point to a valid node.

After inserting a node in the list, we want to make `$pointer` reference the newly created/inserted node.

**Printing the list**

We want to print the entire list from start to end, so we will need to start by finding the start of the list. This is the same operation as `-` applied repeatedly until the first node is found. (The first node is the one which has no previous node.)

Then, it's just a question of traversing the list in the other direction (like `+` does), printing the values as you go along.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! About the + and -, it doesn't change the 'direction' but rather moves the pointer to the previous or the next value, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Adam It does not make sense. In the `A D - B C + E = ABCDE` example. If you have `A*` (where `*` is the pointer location), then `AD*`, `-` changes it to `A*D`, adding B makes it `AB*D` (case 1) if the pointer now resets and points to AFTER B, or `A*BD` (case 2) if it is still in BEFORE mode. Going for the end result, we'd have to assume case 1: `AB*D` if we're going to end up with `ABC*D`, and then `+` would move it to the end `ABCD*`. Still a logical error, and the end string would be, from case 2: `A*BD` => `A*CBD` => `AC*BD` => `ACE*BD`. As before.

Comment: @TLP, It does make sense. You always insert after the current node, and you always make the inserted node the current node (just as in our wrong interpretation). A D - B C + E does produce A B C D E then. ([A] --(D)--> A [D] --(-)-->  [A] D --(B)--> A [B] D --(C)--> A B [C] D --(+)--> A B C [D] --(E)--> A B C D [E])

Comment: Adjusted my answer